# How do I increase the amount of data I can pass back from a RIA Service?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm new to WCF, RIA Services, and even Silverlight for the most part.  I need to know how to increase the amount of data that I can pass back from a RIA service.  I know that I need to create summary lists and I am being smart about how I request data.  I can't use paging because I've archetected myself into a corner, and it would be way too much refactoring at this point.  I just need to double the limit of data coming back.  My requests are fairly small.  How can I do this, and also why is this window so small?

I'm told that I just have to modify ServiceReferences.ClientConfig but I have no idea where or what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with RIA services, you can increase limit of transferring data by increasing http request length. Add this to your Web.config:

> < system.web>
>
> ```
>     < httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
>
>     ...
> ```
>
> < /system.web>

By default this value is 4Mb

Comment: Thanks for your replay.  This has to do with the request size.  I'm having trouble getting the data back __from__ the server.

Comment: Try to use this to change the size of the data sent by DomainService: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/148523.aspx

Comment: Hey, cool, I actually needed to know this for something.  I love when that happens. :) +1