# load operation got stuck on fetching 100000+ records wcf ria services silverlight

Tags: wpf, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

i call a wcf ria services function which returns more than 100,000 records. when i debug the code, the returned object from that function takes normal time to load this much records. but when in the view model's load operation's callback function, it gets stuck there for unlimited time. can anyone please guide me on this.

please check the code of my view model below...

```
EntityQuery<DataSetData> KPIPivotGridViewDataQuery = GridDataContext.GetPivotGridViewKPIDataQuery(KPIInfo.KPI_Id, srcTableName, HelperMethods.GetLanguageID(), dateCol, StDate, EdDate);
            LoadOperation<DataSetData> loPivotGridViewDataQuery =   GridDataContext.Load(KPIPivotGridViewDataQuery);

            loPivotGridViewDataQuery.Completed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                LoadOperation<DataSetData> vals = sender as LoadOperation<DataSetData>;
                if (!vals.HasError)
                {
                    DataSetData data = vals.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
                    IEnumerable KPIPivotGridViewData = DynamicDataBuilder.GetDataList(data);
                    this.PivotGridViewPagedView = new RadGVPagging(KPIPivotGridViewData);//new ObservableCollection<object>(KPIPivotGridViewData.Cast<object>());

                    this.isBusy = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.isBusy = false;
                    //this.BIChart.IsBusy = false;
                    SilverlightMessageBox.ShowErrorDialog(vals.Error.Message, rm.GetString("msgErrorHeading", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture));
                    ISFLogging.AddLog(vals.Error.Message, "GetPivotGridViewData.loChartDataQuery_Completed");
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on how much data you can pass. Maybe check this for how to change it

[How do I increase the amount of data I can pass back from a RIA Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263939/how-do-i-increase-the-amount-of-data-i-can-pass-back-from-a-ria-service)

and also this

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/148523.aspx

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. i already tried this by changing the time and max data transfer limit, but it doesn't work for me. the problem is that i get no exception and in the debug mode compiler never reaches the callback event. any other clue for me ??

Comment: Run up Fiddler and see if the problem is your service not returning the results.

Comment: i already have tried that but it returns the content i needed.

Comment: Not sure, but I would get this if I would return straight IEnumerable rather then doint ToList() from ria domain service. Signature could be IEnumerable but you had to transform it to List before returning it.

Comment: I returns a custom object with following properties                                                              [Include]
        [Association("ListTables", "DataSetName", "DataSetName")]
        [DataMember]
        public Collection<DataTableInfo> Tables { get; set; }


        [Key]
        [DataMember]
        public string DataXML { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string DataSetName { get; set; }